If your goal is to only have only one long running task running at a time is it safe to cancel then immediately create a new one?
I have the following polling task. Its roughly exactly like this but obviously a bit contrived to make the question simple.
class SocketClass {
    private var pollingTask: Task<Void, Never>?
    func startPoll() {
        // Stop previous polling task
        pollingTask?.cancel()
        pollingTask = nil

        pollingTask = Task {
            while !Task.isCancelled {
                // Send ping
                // Wait for pong timeout
                await self.waitForPong()

                // Wait for the next ping interval
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(30_000_000_000))
            }
        }
        // Is it possible that at this point that there are two tasks 
        // attempting to poll before the previous one heard it needed to cancel?
    }

    private func waitForPong(_ uuid: UUID, _ count: Int) async -> Bool {
        let pongReceived = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            socket.once("pong") { [weak self] _, _ in
                continuation.resume(returning: true)
            }
        }
        return pongReceived
    }
}

My concern is when startPoll() is called that the previous polling task may not be canceled by the time the new one starts. I would feel safer if I could await the cancelation of the previous task but not quite sure how to do that.
But with the code as is there are no guarantees that there might be a moment where there are two polling tasks working simultaneously for at least a little bit right? Especially if the ping/pong code doesnt check if the task is canceled.

Sure, it seems inuitively obvious that you could say pollingTask?.cancel() at a time when the task code is sitting on an await; it clearly isn't going to break from the while loop until it passes thru all the awaits.

How are withTimeout and waitForPong implemented? This heavily depends on how they handle task cancellation. It would also help if you can make the code less contrived. Right now I don't see any reason why you can't just reuse the same task when startPoll is called for a second time, instead of creating a brand new task.

Simple answer, yes it can happen that two tasks are running at the same time. If a correct solution requires to avoid this, it actually becomes more difficult than it seems to be: before actually invoking a new task, you need to wait until the current task (if any) has been completed. This inevitable makes startPoll() an async function, in which case it would be possible for several clients to even call it concurrently, which causes yet more subtle problems :). For a robust solution, I would recommend an implementation utilising a FSM, to get all edge cases under control.

@Sweeper I thought of the "subtask" cancellation question too, but decided it isn't really relevant to the question as posed, because the OP is not using structured concurrency. Cancellation is not going to magically trickle down to the await calls. Basically the OP is starting with a bad architecture and then asking, "Is this a bad architecture?" Yes.

@Rob thankyou this is an especially helpful explanation. The bummer in this case is the non structured concurrency library is SocketIO and they do not provide cancellations for any of their operations.

Curious actually. It seems the whole concept of sockets (like waiting until something comes in) is somewhat against the grain of the spirit of structured concurrency? Or am I wrong there. Do you know of a good socket library written in Swift Async?

"Waiting until something comes in" is the job of a AsyncSequence (Rob has also mentioned this).

You could change your task to throw when it is cancelled by calling checkCancellation instead of checking isCancelled.  You can then await pollingTask.result - Once that await completes you know that the task has stopped:
class SocketClass {
    private var pollingTask: Task<Void, Error>?
    func startPoll() {
        // Stop previous polling task
        if let pollingTask {
            pollingTask.cancel()
            let _ = await pollingTask.value
        }

        pollingTask = Task {
            while true {
                Task.checkCancellation()
                // Send ping
                // Wait for pong timeout
                await withTimeout(seconds: pongTimeout) {
                    await self.waitForPong()
                }

                // Wait for the next ping interval
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(30_000_000_000))
            }
        }
    }
}


Your assumption is correct, that there can be a race of the cancellation and starting the poll, which makes it possible, that two operations run at the same time. A solution requires that the start of the operation should only begin, when the previous one (if any) is completed.
The following class solves this issue. Note, that there are other solutions possible.
Note also, that the class is running on the MainActor to make it thread-safe. The function start() cannot overlap when called from multiple clients, however start() can be called, when the internal operation is still running. In this case, the current task is cancelled, then its completion is awaited and only then, the new task will be created and started.
@MainActor
final class Operation {
    var task: Task<Void, Never>?
    var result: Result<String, Error>?
    
    func start() {
        Task { [weak self] in
            if let self {
                self.cancel()
                await self.task?.value
                print("Start operation")
                self.task = makeTask()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        if let task, !task.isCancelled {
            print("Cancel operation")
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    var isRunning: Bool { task != nil }

    private func makeTask() -> Task<Void, Never> {
        Task { [weak self] in
            do {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
                self?.result = .success("Hello, world!")
                self?.task = nil
                print("Operation succeeded.")
            } catch {
                self?.result = .failure(error)
                self?.task = nil
                print("Operation failed with error (\error).")
            }
        }
    }
}

You can visualise and test this class when making it an Observable and show the state in a View:
import Observation

@Observable
@MainActor
final class Operation {
    ... 
}

and a SwiftUI view:
import SwiftUI 

struct ModelView: View {
    @State private var model = Operation()
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView(
            result: model.result,
            isRunning: model.isRunning,
            startOperation: model.start,
            cancelOperation: model.cancel
        )
    } 
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let result: Result<String, Error>?
    let isRunning: Bool
    let startOperation: () -> Void
    let cancelOperation: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if let result {
                    Text("\(result)")
                } else {
                    Text("no result")
                }
                
                Button("Start Operation") {
                    startOperation()
                }
                .padding()
                
                Button("Cancel Operation") {
                    cancelOperation()
                }
                .padding()
            }
            if isRunning {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    }
}


If you are going to poll, the basic idea of pollingTask?.cancel() followed by pollingTask = Task {…} is correct. A few problems, though:

If you are going to have a mutable property (such as Task for the previous polling routine), you need to make SocketClass thread-safe (e.g., make it an actor).

Your waitForPong does not support cancelation. When using withCheckedContinuation, we’d often wrap that in a withTaskCancellationHandler which would invoke whatever cancellation API socket provides, if any.

Implicit in the prior point, the underlying socket library must support cancelation. If it doesn’t, then this would be for naught.

The whole idea of polling is an anti-pattern. Best practice would be to await the receipt of the desired string. But that assumes, of course, that your socket library supports event-driven patterns, or better, async-await.


Assuming this isn’t a “bridge too far”, given that your chosen socket library does not support async-await, cancelation, and event-driven handling, I might suggest cutting the Gordian knot, and adopt one that does. For example, in iOS 13+, macOS 10.15+, etc., one might use the native URLSession web sockets:
actor SocketService {
    let socket: URLSessionWebSocketTask

    init() throws {
        guard let url = URL(string: …) else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }

        socket = URLSession.shared.webSocketTask(with: url)
        socket.resume()
    }

    func end() {
        socket.cancel(with: .normalClosure, reason: nil)
    }

    func send(_ string: String) async throws {
        try await socket.send(.string(string))
    }

    func receive() async throws -> String {
        switch try await socket.receive() {
        case .string(let string): return string
        case .data(let data):     throw SocketServiceError.notString(data)
        default:                  throw SocketServiceError.unknownPayloadType
        }
    }

    func waitForPong() async throws {
        while !Task.isCancelled {
            let string = try await receive()
            if string == "pong" {
                return
            } else {
                print("received \(string), expecting pong")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SocketService {
    enum SocketServiceError: Error {
        case notString(Data)
        case unknownPayloadType
    }
}

Then you can do things like:
do {
    try await socketService.waitForPong()
    print("received pong")
} catch {
    print(error)
}

For example, I used an “echo” service (wss://echo.websocket.org/) and did the following:
do {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        try await socketService.send("\(i)")
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
    }
    try await socketService.send("pong")
} catch {
    print(error)
}

And the waitForPong produced:
received Request served by 1781505b56ee58, expecting pong
received 0, expecting pong
received 1, expecting pong
received 2, expecting pong
received 3, expecting pong
received 4, expecting pong
received 5, expecting pong
received 6, expecting pong
received 7, expecting pong
received 8, expecting pong
received 9, expecting pong
received pong


No threads were blocked and, as you can see, the above renders polling necessary, thereby eliminating all the concomitant issues regarding canceling prior task, etc. You can even create asynchronous sequences for values received via sockets.
If you are really stuck using this legacy sockets framework, then maybe you can explain the broader problem and maybe we can provide alternatives (e.g., in the absence of cancelation support, you will want to adopt a pattern that avoids overlapping polling calls). It is hard to advise you in the abstract.
